# Printing Out Timesteps For Game of Life

Tags: c, conways-game-of-life

I am writing a Game of Life code and that simulation will run for 1000 timesteps. The program seems to be running well, but I want to add another feature where the timesteps will be printed out on top of the current state of the board. For example, on `timestep = 0`, the initial board will be printed out and on `timestep = 1000` the final state of the board will be printed out.

I have thought of the following code to print out the timestep (note: I am still a beginner at learning *C* programming):

```
int timestep = 1000;
printf("Timestep: ");
for (int init_time = 0; init_time < timestep; init_time++)
{
    printf("%d", init_time);
}
```

I am not sure whether this code will print out this way: [*Timestep Sample Image (Click Here)*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEZaR.png)

I am thinking that a row needs to be cleared out to print out the timestep, but I am not sure how to do that or if this is even the correct approach to solving that issue. I will appreciate any kind of help that you can offer.

Comment: That code would work (compile and run), but not how you want it to. Instead, try doing: `printf("%d\n", init_time);` That will print the number, add a line feed so the board is printed on the next line, and it will not increment the `init_time` variable twice (which is what your current code is doing).

Comment: @SpencerDoak That seems like a good fix so I will try that out. But may I know where to exactly place that line of code? I have three functions: (1) assigning the initial values of the board (dead or alive), (2) generating the next generation and wrapping around the board if it is out of bounds, and (3) printing out the board. Should I place `printf("%d\n")` in the beginning of the printing out the board function?

Comment: @math_user, without seeing your entire code, I cannot tell you exactly where to place it, but probably either in your function to print the board or on the line before the call to print the board. If you put it inside the function that prints the board, then just make sure the `init_time` variable is in scope.

Comment: @SpencerDoak, if you click on the link then you can see what my print board function looks like: https://postimg.org/image/aoa1q3t7b/

Comment: @SpencerDoak, the timesteps are printing out properly but I can only see them if I scroll up the window. I am pretty sure that I have to use fix the terminal window size so that the timesteps, along with the board, are printed out properly. Do you have any suggestions as to how I can do that? Or are there any other alternative fixes that you think can solve this issue?

Comment: Please clarify whether the count and board are meant to be printed to *stdout* as a scrolling display, (a 10x10 board of 100 cycles would scroll off the terminal for 1100 lines), or as a single screen, (a 10x10 board of 100 lines would be animated on 11 lines of the screen).

Comment: I believe that it should be printed out as as a standard output with the scrolling display.